# Argument must be int or float

Tags: python, django

I was trying to render data to my database from backend using "python manage.py shell" command and I got this error attached.[Screen short of the "python manage.py shell" command and the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC0nC.jpg)

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.